# How to make text wrap around a table, as if it were an image

Tags: html, css, tabular

I'm surprised I couldn't find a solution to this. I would like to position a small table (1 row, 3 cells,) near the top of my document, aligned to the right, with a paragraph wrapping around it, just as you can do with an image with the following code...

```
    <img src="http://www.sorenwagner.ws/marty/img/ca-seal.jpg"
        align="right" width="300" height="100">
    This is a paragraph large enough to wrap around the image...
    This is a paragraph large enough to wrap around the image...
    This is a paragraph large enough to wrap around the image...
    This is a paragraph large enough to wrap around the image...
```

It would be nice as well to be able to define padding around the table, so the text is not right up to the border. Is there a relatively simple solution for this in CSS?

Comment: Since your question's been fully-addressed in three different responses, it's proper etiquette to choose an answer so this isn't seen as 'unanswered' for other users referencing this in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Just [float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float) the table to the right (which is how you should be positioning the image as well):

```
<table style="float: right">
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
<p>Bunch of text...</p>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZLfg7/1/

Answer (score 5):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nq6ez/)

```
table {
    float: right; /* floats the table to the right,
                     allowing text to wrap around it */
    margin: 12px; /* adds buffer space around the table */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Float the table right and give it a margin via CSS:

```
table {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 0 10px 10px;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q58hq/)**.

Comment: OP asked to have space between the table and its parent. `margin:0 0 10px 10px` only applies space to the bottom and left sides of the table.

Comment: @gmeben - Actually the OP said, "It would be nice as well to be able to define padding around the table, so the text is not right up to the border." which I did in my example. Besides, altering the amount of margin is trivial.